# 52 Card Deck Probability

Tags: probability

A deck of cards contains 52 cards, 26 red and 26 black.
A card is chosen at random.

What is the probability that the card is black or a king?

$(P) = 26/52 + 4/52 = 30/52$

Is this correct?

Comment: Calculate $P[black] + P[king] - P[black~and~king]$ (to avoid overcounting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to subtract off the probability that a card is black and is a king i.e. $2/52$ (the king of clubs and spades). The correct probability is 
$$
28/52.
$$
We are using the fact that 
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)
$$
where $A$ is the event of black card being drawn and $B$ is the event of a king card being drawn.

In your computation we are counting the king of spades and king of clubs twice which is why we subtract off the probability of the intersection.